# How can I add an attribute to the error template model?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

When Spring returns a 404 response the [DefaultErrorViewResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/error/DefaultErrorViewResolver.html) will return an error view such as `/<static>/error/404.html`. In my case this is a Thymeleaf template.

I would like to add an attribute "X" to the model for all of the error templates; `error/4xx`, `error/404`, `error/5xx`, etc.

In a `@Controller` I would use the `@ModelAttribute` annotation to add an attribute to each `@RequestMapping` however this is not possible for exception handling views:

> Model enhancement methods (for adding additional data to the model)
>   annotated with @ModelAttribute. Note that these attributes are not
>   available to the exception handling views.

https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#using-controlleradvice-classes

Comment: Interesting if it could be achieved; doubt it given what you quoted though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I eventually ended up doing:

```
@Component
public class AdditionalErrorAttributes extends DefaultErrorAttributes {

    private final SomeService service;

    public AdditionalErrorAttributes(SomeService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(WebRequest webRequest, boolean includeStackTrace) {
        Map<String, Object> errorAttributes = super.getErrorAttributes(webRequest, includeStackTrace);

        errorAttributes.put("someAttribute", service.getAttribute());

        return errorAttributes;
    }
}
```